# Parse.com, Push notification Xamarin Android

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.android

guys!
I am trying to implement push notifications into Xamarin.Android  project by using parse.com, but cannot find anything to for it. I can send message to parse but cannot receive it on device , could someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The parse library for Xamarin don't support Push notifications. I recommend you use other Push services, like Azure, that supports it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In Get More Components you can search parse. downloaded it and use it.

My Suggestion is to go with Azure notification hub or 
[Tap Target](http://taptarget.com/).

Please feel free to ask more question about xamarin push notificaitons.

Answer (score 0):

Parse is now supporting Push Notification for Xamarin.iOS and Android. https://twitter.com/ParseIt/status/601503406805520384